# Generate NACHA file using PHP?

Tags: php

I am trying to generate a bank NACHA (national automated clearing house association) file with my customers payment details to submit to my bank on a regular basis. Our site is built in PHP and though we could *probably* build the file ourselves, I was curious if anybody knew of any existing scripts or even reference guides for others who have done so using PHP.

I have searched around Google pretty hard unsuccessfully so any assistance is appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 9):

I also needed such a thing... didn't find one so I made one.

https://github.com/snsparrish/NachaLibPHP

Comment: Perfect. I'll be needing this soon. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: @Shawn - thanks for the link. I actually ended up building myself back in 2010 and forgot to come back here and share the code (though it was written in pretty bad PHP, it has worked well for 3 years). It is also highly customized to our business so I'll see if I can strip some of the customization and share as you have.

Answer (score 4):

The National ACH Association "NACHA" publishes the ACH rules on an annual basis.  The current version, "2012 NACHA OPERATING RULES & GUIDELINES", contains the ACH rules, along with ACH file formats (i.e. Reference Guide) for creating your own tools to build ACH files.

http://www.achrulesonline.org/

Answer (score 0):

Most businesses that need to create these files are .net houses. You might have better luck finding something in C# and reverse-engineering it.

Comment: i went ahead and wrote my own script. Not much into reverse-engineering other languages ;)

Comment: Since you had so much trouble finding one, it would be really nice of you to go post your solution around the web.

Comment: i might end up doing so but the code is laden with several variables and private data that wouldn't apply in most NACHA file format processes. I will spend some time to go back through and update soon.