# Need to create NACHA file with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, lamp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generate NACHA file using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195277/generate-nacha-file-using-php)

Have you created a NACHA file in PHP? If so, would you be interested in posting the script at least in part so we can use. Or perhaps, post the NACHA file format standards so we could build? Open to providers who can accomplish for us as well..Any suggestion would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: No one can post the NACHA spec. It must be purchased. What exactly are you wanting to send. NACHA files are very flexible and can contain many different types of transactions.